# Are most third party packages in Python safe to use with Django and Nginx?

Tags: python, django, nginx, thread-safety

So I have been developing an app using the Django Platform, and recently I have been thinking about scalability in the app. I currently am developing this app in a civil engineering research lab, and we don't get a ton of traffic on our current server.

I was wondering if some of the apps we develop are able to take multiple requests at the same time in our labs. From my understanding, they should, based on how well the server we are using is configured (Nginx in our case, I believe). From what I understand (please correct me if I wrong) our server has some workers (or threads, I think they are the same thing) that will accept requests, then they will go through the code that I have written and generate responses based on what the request is.

My main question is **if I am using third party packages, how well will they scale if my app was getting more traffic?** For example, if I used pandas/numpy/numba/etc... in my controllers, would this be safe when we have multiple users sending requests to multiple threads?

**EDIT:** I changed the wording of the question as it was worded a bit poorly initially.

Comment: In Django use signals and threads the regular way, along with message queues such as Celery or RQ. Ship that logic out of your views into callbacks and signals, where make the processing multithreaded.

Comment: nginx workers are typically processes, not threads.

Comment: @DanielRoseman So for every user that goes onto my app, a different process will be created through Nginx?

Comment: No, it uses a fixed pool of workers.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Ok, so when the pool runs out users have to wait? (e.g. if I have ten worker processes and they are all full, the server will wait for the 11th user until one of the workers free up) Also, since Nginx is using processes, does that mean that the third party python apps will be fine and won't conflict with other concurrent workers? Sorry if these question are really dumb, I am just wanting to learn more about what goes on behind the scenes in a web application

Comment: Yes, both of those are correct. As dmitryro said though, if you have tasks that take a long time you should probably extract them into asynchronous jobs using something like Celery, so that the requests can complete quickly and don't get blocked.